# Expose an interface of a class loaded from a framework at runtime

Tags: swift, dylib, dlopen

I want to load and manipulate [`SKUIImageColorAnalyzer`](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/StoreKitUI.framework/SKUIImageColorAnalyzer.h) and
[`SKUIAnalyzedImageColors`](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/StoreKitUI.framework/SKUIAnalyzedImageColors.h) objects from the private `StoreKitUI.framework`.

First, I attempt to load the framework at runtime:

```
guard case let libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreKitUI.framework/StoreKitUI", RTLD_NOW) where libHandle != nil else {
    fatalError("StoreKitUI not found")
}
```

Then, I verify that the `SKUIImageColorAnalyzer` class can be found:

```
guard let analyzerClass: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("SKUIImageColorAnalyzer")  else {
    fatalError("SKUIImageColorAnalyzer lookup failed")
}
```

I want to use the `analyzeImage:` class method on `SKUIImageColorAnalyzer`, which takes in a `UIImage` for analysis and returns an `SKUIAnalyzedImageColors` object. I do this by verifying the `analyzeImage:` selector exists on the `SKUIImageColorAnalyzer` object, and recreate the function:

```
let selector: Selector = "analyzeImage:"
guard case let method = class_getClassMethod(analyzerClass, selector) where method != nil else {
    fatalError("failed to look up \(selector)")
}

// recreate the method's implementation function
typealias Prototype = @convention(c) (AnyClass, Selector, UIImage) -> AnyObject? // returns an SKUIAnalyzedImageColors object
let opaqueIMP = method_getImplementation(method)
let function = unsafeBitCast(opaqueIMP, Prototype.self)
```

Now, I can get a `UIImage` object and pass that in as the argument to the function:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "someImage.jpg")!
let analyzedImageColors = function(analyzerClass, selector, img) // <SKUIAnalyzedImageColors: 0x7f90d3408eb0>
```

I know that `analyzedImageColors` is of type `SKUIAnalyzedImageColors`, but the compiler still thinks its type is `AnyObject` based on the way I declared `Prototype` above. Now I want to access the properties of an `SKUIAnalyzedImageColors` object.

From the [header](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/StoreKitUI.framework/SKUIAnalyzedImageColors.h), I can see that there are properties such as `backgroundColor`, `textPrimaryColor`, and `textSecondaryColor` on the object. I can access these properties using `valueForKey`, but I'd like to expose a public interface on `SKUIAnalyzedImageColors` so I can access these properties.

My first attempt was something like this:

```
// Create a "forward declaration" of the class
class SKUIAnalyzedImageColors: NSObject { }


// Create convenience extensions for accessing properties
extension SKUIAnalyzedImageColors {
    func backgroundColor() -> UIColor {
        return self.valueForKey("_backgroundColor") as! UIColor
    }

    func textPrimaryColor() -> UIColor {
        return self.valueForKey("_textPrimaryColor") as! UIColor
    }

    func textSecondaryColor() -> UIColor {
        return self.valueForKey("_textSecondaryColor") as! UIColor
    }
}

// ...

// modify the prototype to return an SKUIAnalyzedImageColors object
typealias Prototype = @convention(c) (AnyClass, Selector, UIImage) -> SKUIAnalyzedImageColors?

// ...

// access the properties from the class extension
analyzedImageColors?.backgroundColor() // Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.262745 0.231373 0.337255 1)
```

This still requires me to use `valueForKey`. Is there a way to expose a public interface on a class from a framework loaded at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do dynamic Objective-C stuff is to use Objective-C.

*ImageAnalyzer.h:*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface SKUIAnalyzedImageColors : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIColor* backgroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isBackgroundLight;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIColor* textPrimaryColor;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIColor* textSecondaryColor;

@end

SKUIAnalyzedImageColors* _Nullable analyzeImage(UIImage* image);

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

*ImageAnalyzer.m:*

```
#import "ImageColorAnalyzer.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>

static Class _SKUIImageColorAnalyzerClass;

@interface SKUIImageColorAnalyzer : NSObject
+ (SKUIAnalyzedImageColors*)analyzeImage:(UIImage*)arg1;
@end

SKUIAnalyzedImageColors* analyzeImage(UIImage* image)
{
    if (!_SKUIImageColorAnalyzerClass)
    {
        if (!dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreKitUI.framework/StoreKitUI", RTLD_NOW))
        {
            NSLog(@"No framework.");
            return nil;
        }
        _SKUIImageColorAnalyzerClass = NSClassFromString(@"SKUIImageColorAnalyzer");
        if (!_SKUIImageColorAnalyzerClass)
        {
            NSLog(@"No Class.");
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return [_SKUIImageColorAnalyzerClass analyzeImage:image];
}
```

You can then use the `analyzeImage` function and the `SKUIAnalyzedImageColors` class easily from either Swift or Objective-C code.

```
if let image = UIImage(named:"MyImage") {
    if let colors = analyzeImage(image) {
        print("Background Color: \(colors.backgroundColor)")
    }
}
```

If you really want to do it all in Swift, first declare the parts of the `SKUIAnalyzedImageColors` Objective-C interface you want to use:

```
@objc protocol ImageColors {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor { get }
    var isBackgroundLight: Bool { get }
    var textPrimaryColor: UIColor { get }
    var textSecondaryColor: UIColor { get }
}
```

Then use `unsafeBitCast` to cast the opaque object instance to your desired Objective-C interface:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "someImage.jpg")!
let rawAnalyzedImageColors = function(analyzerClass, selector, img) 

let analyzedImageColors = unsafeBitCast(rawAnalyzedImageColors, ImageColors.self)
print("Background color: \(analyzedImageColors.backgroundColor)")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking for a pure Swift solution without the use of Objective-C.  If I wanted to use Objective-C, I could take the headers dumped from the framework and import them through a bridging header to expose the classes and interfaces.

Comment: Additionally, your pure Swift solution still requires me to expose an interface through a protocol.  Is there a way to dynamically load the interface of that object, rather than have to declare everything by hand?

Comment: I do appreciate your reflection approach though, +1 regardless.

Comment: @JAL Whether you use Objective-C or Swift you must declare the interface you want to use yourself and then cast the object to that interface.  The compiler and the runtime take care of the rest.  If it were a public framework then it would provide a header that declares the public interface for you.  Because it's private, you have to declare the interface yourself.

Comment: I understand.  I guess i just hoped that loading the classes from the framework would also load each object's interface.  It appears that the reflection approach is the best implementation for Swift.  Thanks.

Comment: @JAL There is no reflection here.  We're declaring an public interface and telling the compiler that an object instance conforms to that interface.  This allows the compiler to use regular Objective-C method dispatch.

Comment: Ah you're right, I misread the last part of your answer with the unsafeBitCast.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, thank you for your research.